# Sprite is white square in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have created template that would hold pointer to any kind of asset and its id called ResourceHolder but when i use pointer to texture from instance of this template to load texture to sprite it is white square.
Here is my code in ResourceHolder.hpp:

```
#ifndef RESOURCEEHOLDER_H
#define RESOURCEHOLDER_H
#include "TexturesId.h"
#include "assert.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace sf;
template<typename Resource,typename Identifier>

class ResourceHolder
{
    public:
        void load(Identifier id,const std::string &filename);
        Resource& get(Identifier id);
        const Resource& get(Identifier id) const;
    protected:

    private:
        std::map<Identifier,std::unique_ptr<Resource>> mResourceMap;
};

#endif // TEXTUREHOLDER_H
```

Then code in ResourceHolder.cpp

```
#include "ResourceHolder.h"
using namespace sf;

template<typename Resource,typename Identifier>
void ResourceHolder<Resource,Identifier>::load(Identifier id,const std::string& filename)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> resource(new Resource());
    if(!(resource->loadFromFile(filename)))
       {
           throw std::runtime_error("TextureHolder failed to load " + filename);
       }
    auto inserted=mResourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(id,std::move(resource)));
    assert(inserted.second);
}
template<typename Resource,typename Identifier>
Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource,Identifier>::get(Identifier id)
{
    auto found=mResourceMap.find(id);
    assert(found!=mResourceMap.end());
    return *found->second;
}
template<typename Resource,typename Identifier>
const Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource,Identifier>::get(Identifier id) const
{
    auto found=mResourceMap.find(id);
    assert(found!=mResourceMap.end());
    return *found->second;
}
template class ResourceHolder<Texture,Textures::ID>;
```

TextureId.h:

```
#ifndef TEXTURESID_H_INCLUDED
#define TEXTURESID_H_INCLUDED
namespace Textures
{
    enum ID{Landsape,Airplane,Missile};
}

#endif // TEXTURESID_H_INCLUDED
```

and finally in Game.cpp

```
Game::Game(int x,int y,std::string &Name)
:window(VideoMode(x,y),Name),texture(),
mPlayer()
{
    ResourceHolder<Texture,Textures::ID> th;
    th.load(Textures::ID::Airplane,"plane.png");
    Texture texture=th.get(Textures::ID::Airplane);
    mPlayer.setTexture(texture);
    mPlayer.setPosition(window.getSize().x/2,window.getSize().y/2);
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Read carefully reference of `setTexture`: *The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite doesn't store its own copy of the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function.*, your texture is LOCAL.

Comment: SFML mentions this problem in the tutorial: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic code is the one in Game.cpp

```cpp
Game::Game(int x,int y,std::string &Name)
:window(VideoMode(x,y),Name),texture(),
mPlayer()
{
    ResourceHolder<Texture,Textures::ID> th;
    th.load(Textures::ID::Airplane,"plane.png");
    Texture texture=th.get(Textures::ID::Airplane);
    mPlayer.setTexture(texture);
    mPlayer.setPosition(window.getSize().x/2,window.getSize().y/2);
}
```

`ResourceHolder` as well as `Texture` only exist in the local scope of the `Game` constructor. Once the constructor has been executed, both the `rh` and `texture` will run out of scope and the sprite's reference to the texture is invalidated, which leads to the [white square problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem).

Comment: Thanks buddy, cant believe I made such amateurish mistake

Comment: No worries, everyone has to start somewhere. Don't forget to accept my answer as solution, if it fixed your issue.